# How to restructure a data frame with time data split at regular interval (and compute updated durations)

Tags: r, time, split, duration

I have a data frame as below:

```
tab <- data.frame(Behav = c("Rest","Eat","Eat"),      
              Behav.start= c("14:10:40","14:13:25","17:35:00"),
              Behav.end = c("14:13:24","17:31:05","17:37:25"), 
              Behav.dur.s = c("164","19060","145"))

Behav    Behav.start    Behav.end    Behav.dur.s
 Rest     14:10:40       14:13:24      164
 Eat      14:13:25       17:31:05      11860
 Eat      17:35:00       17:37:25      145
```

N.B. 'Behav.dur.s' = time interval (in seconds) between 'Behav.start' and 'Behav.end'

I want to compute an hourly time budget, in other words, I want to compute how long an individual spent resting, eating, etc., during each interval of 1 hour.

Then, I tried (but failed..) to restructure my initial data frame tab to obtain a new data frame such as a row with a behavior lasting more than an hour (Behav.dur.s > 3600) is replaced with n 'duplicated' rows with the given behavior lasting 1 hour interval, updating Behav.start, Behav.end and Behav.dur.s

```
Behav    Behav.start    Behav.end    Behav.dur.s
 Rest     14:10:40       14:13:24      164
 Eat      14:13:25       15:00:00      2795
 Eat      15:00:00       16:00:00      3600
 Eat      16:00:00       17:00:00      3600
 Eat      17:00:00       17:31:05      1865
 Eat      17:35:00       17:37:25      145
```

Then, I will be able to compute an hourly time budget.

I'd really appreciate some help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following steps with below assumptions that uses a cross join across all 24 hours in a day, then subsets to specific duration, and finally re-calculates start/end points.

#### Assumptions

- Time originates in string format of `HH:MM` as posted;
- Times range only within **one** single day (i.e., time within midnight, `00:00` to `23:59` of one day). Otherwise split by day and `rbind` together;
- Data in *tab* is reasonably sized as the cross join will add (before subsetting) 24 rows for *every* row of tab.

#### Steps

1. **Data Build/Conversion**

   ```
   # CONVERT TIMES TO POSIXct TYPES
   tab <- within(tab, {
     Behav.start = as.POSIXct(Behav.start, tz="GMT", format="%H:%M:%S")
     Behav.end = as.POSIXct(Behav.end, tz="GMT", format="%H:%M:%S")
   })

   # BUILD DF OF ALL 24 HOURS DURATIONS FOR CURRENT DATE
   hours_df <- data.frame(start_hour = as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + c(0:23)*60*60),
                          end_hour = as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + c(1:24)*60*60))
   ```
2. **Cross Join + Subset**

   ```
   mdf <- merge(tab, hours_df, all=TRUE)

   sdf <- subset(mdf, Behav.start <= end_hour & Behav.end >= start_hour)
   ```
3. **Calculate Final Start/End**

   ```
   final_df <- within(sdf, {
     final_start <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(Behav.start > start_hour, Behav.start, start_hour),
                               tz="GMT", origin="1970-01-01")
     final_end <- as.POSIXct(ifelse(Behav.end < end_hour, Behav.end, end_hour),
                             tz="GMT", origin="1970-01-01")

     final_dur <- as.numeric(difftime(final_end, final_start, units="secs"))

     rm(Behav.start, Behav.end, start_hour, end_hour, Behav.dur.s)

   })[c("Behav", "final_start", "final_end", "final_dur")]

   # CONVERT DATE/TIME TO STRING TIME
   final_df <- data.frame(within(final_df, {
      final_start <- format(final_start, format="%H:%M:%S")
      final_end <- format(final_end, format="%H:%M:%S")
   }), row.names = NULL)

   final_df
   #   Behav final_start final_end final_dur
   # 1  Rest    14:10:40  14:13:24       164
   # 2   Eat    14:13:25  15:00:00      2795
   # 3   Eat    15:00:00  16:00:00      3600
   # 4   Eat    16:00:00  17:00:00      3600
   # 5   Eat    17:00:00  17:31:05      1865
   # 6   Eat    17:35:00  17:37:25       145
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and annotated answer !
It works perfectly :)

Comment: C'est parfait? Great to hear and glad to help!

Comment: C'est parfait ;-)